# How to perform transactional batch operation in Azure cosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Recently Microsoft introduced [Transactional Batch operation capability](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-transactionalbatch-in-the-net-sdk/) in Azure CosmosDB offering.
In all the samples and per documentation, it seems that all operations within a batch need to be in the same partition. Wondering if there is a way to achieve Transactional Batch operations across the partition.

My use case is to create thousands of documents and the partition key is the document id. In each operation, I create 2 documents (with the same id) that are in the same partition and I need to do them as part of the transaction. I need to batch thousands of such operations.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199588/272109). Tl;dr no way to have atomic operations outside the scope of a partition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, no, there is no way to achieve transactions across distributed partitions.

Both Transactional Batch or Stored Procedures are executed and generate the transaction scope at the Partition Key level.